# Network CHM file

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2012, intranet, chm

So I've read about CHM files on the network(intranet) and how to view them on windows. It works.
The problem is Visual Studio can't view them still.

```
Help.ShowHelp(ParentForm, @"\\ServerName\data\DynamicHelp\HelpFIle.chm", HelpNavigator.Topic, @"mk:@MSITStore:\\ServerName\data\\DynamicHelp\HelpFile.chm::/TopicName.htm");
```

The result is Help File which is empty.
The topics and subtopics are all present in the content list, but nothing within them.

If anyone knows how to fix this please, share your expertise with me.

Comment: There is a similar post but without a working answer for this question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to change a registry setting to allow the .chm file viewer to access content on a network drive. I do this by applying this .reg file:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\HTMLHelp\1.x\ItssRestrictions]
"MaxAllowedZone"=dword:00000001

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\HTMLHelp\1.x\ItssRestrictions]
"MaxAllowedZone"=dword:00000001
```

Note that I apply the setting in both 32 and 64 bit views of the registry.

And I know that I am breaking the golden rule by hard-coding `Wow6432Node`, but for my needs, on my particular network, this suffices.

Comment: Sorry for late reply. I also needed to add Path exception to the registry in order to access the file on server as such:
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\HTMLHelp\1.x\ItssRestrictions]
"MaxAllowedZone"=dword:00000004
"UrlAllowList"="[FolderNetworkPath]"

Comment: May I ask what are the risks of using this registry edit when remote centers access the chm file via vpn, if any?

Comment: That's a question for your sysadmin. I am not in a position to comment on your network security.

Comment: Thank you for your response and sharing of knowledge

Comment: So, does this answer your question?